# Repeat_elements function to repeat columns of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

i've read documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/repeat_elements?hl=ID

```
>>> b = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
>>> tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(b, rep=2, axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32,
    numpy=array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32)>
```

the problem is the result is not what i expected

the result i really want is

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32,
        numpy=array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>
```

how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
b = tf.tile(a, [2])
print(b)
```

will print

```
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 1 2 3], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)
```

(or if you really want to go down the `tf.keras.backend` route then the same thing but with `tf.keras.backend.tile(a, [2])`)